# Android Request Permission annotation conditional

Tags: android, android-12, runtime-permissions

I am building an SDK API with beacons integration which requires Bluetooth scan permission for android 12 and above. So, I added annotation for the API like this:

```
@RequiresPermission(allOf = [Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN])
fun enableBeaconScan()
```

When I add this, I am getting a warning:

[image]

Is there a way to restrict this permission only for the supported android versions and get rid of this warning?

Comment: Di you find any solution?

Answer (score -1):

you can use this annotation

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)

Comment: If I use this, the entire API is marked as requires API S, I want the permission only to be annotated and asked for the Build.VERSION_CODES.S and above